# 'Errno::ENOENT no such file/directory' intermittently with FactoryGirl & RSpec/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails, spork

Getting a bizarre error on my RSpec tests, intermittently, on different examples. They all pass 99.999% of the time (and did up until an hour or so ago) leading me to believe there's something crazy going on with my Spork setup. Maybe?

The most recent relevant failure (but it's happening intermittently on lots of different examples, only ever one at a time on a file of ~60 examples)

```
 Failure/Error: @person = create(:person)
 Errno::ENOENT:
   No such file or directory - /Users/jon/Code/help-me-write/tmp/cache/cached-slugs%2Fpeople%7C081706ccee3f19f01752ba7b60dec0f901a746fe4e3f8c00b70ee6671669c80220130514-24434-1byq6eq
 # ./spec/controllers/ideas_controller_spec.rb:153:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's a Gist with the whole file (which I don't this is actually important in this case), and my spec_helper.rb (which I think probably is)

https://gist.github.com/jongd/854669388bec56f69910

Annoying - rerunning the tests or restarting Guard/Spork makes the failing example pass fine. How can I stop this bug from happening?